# How to format an integer as two digits?

Tags: php

```
function months(){
    for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++)
    if($i<10)   {
    echo '<option value="'."0".$i.'">'."0".$i.'</option>';
    }
    else{
    echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
    }
}
```

This populates a dropdown with `01, 02, 03...` instead of `1, 2, 3...`

So, I concatenated `0` and `$i` if `$i<10` and it works, but maybe it is possible by formatting `$i` as two digits, or some similar, shorter method ?

Comment: PHP's built-in [`str_pad()`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php), among other methods.

Comment: Well, you can certainly write it shorter.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all. Seems solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding another variable you could shorten it to:

```
function months(){
    for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++)
         $mo = ($i<10) ? "0".$i : $i;
         echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$mo.'</option>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't want the value itself to be two digits, only the display.

```
echo '<option value="' . $i . '">' . sprintf('%02d', $i) . '</option>';
```

Comment: value is not formated as required

Comment: @Salim: Value should **never** be formatted.

Comment: you are right but his requirements is like 
<option value="'."0".$i.'">'."0".$i.'</option>

Comment: And? I'm saving him from pain he'll experience later. "Why doesn't 08 work? *cry*"

Answer (score 3):

you can use `str_pad`

```
$str = str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: Second argument must be 2 as required

Answer (score 2):

```
function months() {
  for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i ++) {
    $number = sprintf("%02d", $i);
    echo '<option value="' . $number . '">' . $number . '</option>';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use str_pad like this -

```
   function months(){
        for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++) {
         echo '<option    value="'.str_pad($i,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT).'">"'.str_pad($i,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT).'</option>';    
        }    

    }
```